# AngularJS: Directives w/ Templates Referencing Directives and Data Binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.3.  I have a use case where I'm invoking one directive from within another.  In other words, the directives are chained.  I'd like to have a scope variable on my outer directive be updated based on the result of the inner directive.  I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gstanek/6voytwuc/30/ that shows what I've attempted.

The same code is reproduced here:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span first-layer-directive first-layer-info="'fist layer text'"></span>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

});

myApp.directive('firstLayerDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            firstLayerInfo: '='
        },
        template: "<div><span>1st Layer Displayed info='{{firstLayerDisplay}}'</span></div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<span second-layer-directive second-layer-info=\"'second layer text'\" info=\"info\">Second layer displayed info='{{secondLayerDisplay}}'</span></div>" + "<span>Info returned from 2nd layer: {{info}}</span>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.firstLayerDisplay = scope.firstLayerInfo;
            scope.info = '';
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('secondLayerDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            secondLayerInfo: '=',
            info: '='
        },
        template: "<div><span>2nd Layer Displayed info='{{secondLayerDisplay}}'</span></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.secondLayerDisplay = scope.secondLayerInfo + ' plus more info';
            scope.info='info generated in 2nd layer';
        }
    };
});
```

The output of running this JSFiddle is:

```
1st Layer Displayed info='fist layer text'
2nd Layer Displayed info='second layer text plus more info'
Info returned from 2nd layer:
```

Instead, I'd like the last line to display the following:
`Info returned from 2nd layer: info generated in 2nd layer`

How do I pass data back from the inner directive into the outer direct and ensure that the outer directive is updated with the new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access scope of inner directive from outer directive. so just remove below line from link funciton of firstLayerDirective.

```
scope.info = '';
```

You will get you result by doing this if i understood your question correct.

Comment: This does seem to resolve the problem described, but I'm left wondering why.  If the outer directive does see the scope of the inner directive, and  `scope.info` is updated in the inner directive, why wouldn't it also be updated in the outer directive even when `scope.info` is initially set to a blank string? Thanks!

Comment: In you case, you have defined Link funcition in both diretives. you didn't mentioned pre link or post link so it work as Post link function. So, "secondLayerDirective"'s link function will execute first and then link function of "firstLayerDirective" will execute. So finally scope.info will set to blank. One more thing you are using isolated scope, it is not like one time binding. Whenever parent directive changes the value, child directive gets the change.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
As the OP pointed out, the original solution "works" but it's really not correct. I believe the reason this is happening is because of the way inline templates are compiled in conjunction with link functions. If you change the link function to use the preLink it appears to work.

```
link: {
          pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.firstLayerDisplay = scope.firstLayerInfo;
            scope.info = '';
            }
        }
```

---

***Original Answer***

In order to fix this, you need to use what is called "dot-notation" (see here for explanation http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html).

If you change your parent directive to look like the code below it should fix the issue you were seeing...

```
myApp.directive('firstLayerDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            firstLayerInfo: '='
        },
        template: "<div><span>1st Layer Displayed info='{{firstLayerDisplay}}'</span></div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<span second-layer-directive second-layer-info=\"'second layer text'\" info=\"info.text\">Second layer displayed info='{{secondLayerDisplay}}'</span></div>" + "<span>Info returned from 2nd layer: {{info}}</span>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.firstLayerDisplay = scope.firstLayerInfo;
            scope.info.text = '';
        }
    };
});
```

The only changes I made were changing "scope.info = ''" to "scope.info.text = ''" and then passing along "info.text" to the child directive in the html.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The changes you've indicated do _seem_ to solve the issue observed, but I don't think they solve it because of the dot notation pattern.  Instead, it appears that trying to set `scope.into.text` in the `firstLayerDirective` resulted in an initialization error: `angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot set property 'text' of undefined`.  That side-effect made it so the variable was not initialized in the `firstLayerDirective`, which resulted in the same solution noted by @HardikPatel . If I initialize first, `scope.info = {};`, then set the text on it: `scope.info.text = '';`, the issue remains

Comment: You're right, my bad! I'm going to update my answer as I think I have found the issue. It has to do with the link function and inline templates. I think you need to set your scope variables in the pre-link or else the template gets compiled prior to the scope getting set and then stuff gets all out of whack.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your input and you posting the code for the `pre` definition.  Given @HardikPatel went into detail around the reason for the behavior seen, I've marked his reply as the answer

Comment: All good! I don't care about the accepted answer, just glad it got figured out!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `ng-transclude`.

I've made an example for you, look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/smallyin/9nwd0bge/)

same code is reproduced here:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = "I'm foo!";
    $scope.lines = [];
    $scope.addLine = function () {
        $scope.lines.push($scope.lines.length);
    }; 
});

myApp.directive('firstLayerDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            firstLayerInfo: '='
        },
        transclude:true,
        template: "<div><span>1st Layer Displayed info='{{firstLayerDisplay}}'</span></div><div ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.firstLayerDisplay = scope.firstLayerInfo;
            scope.info = '';
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('secondLayerDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            secondLayerInfo: '=',
            info: '='
        },
        template: "<div><span>2nd Layer Displayed info='{{secondLayerDisplay}}'</span></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.secondLayerDisplay = scope.secondLayerInfo + ' plus more info';
            scope.info='info generated in 2nd layer';
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addLine()">Add a line</button>
    <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
        I'm a new line. {{foo}}
    </div>
    <span first-layer-directive first-layer-info="'fist layer text'">
      <div><span second-layer-directive second-layer-info="'second layer text'" info="info">Second layer displayed info='{{secondLayerDisplay}}'</span></div><span>Info returned from 2nd layer: {{info}}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  In my use case, I'd prefer to keep both scopes isolate, and only pass back information needed.  Given that, the `ng-transclude` option doesn't work well for me in my larger use case.  This wasn't clear from my initial question, so I appreciate your input